# Intermittent connection issues to a particular website

Tags: wireless-networking, ssl, connection, web, tls

I am facing connection issues with a website. All of them seem to be connected:

The website host name: napi.kotaksecurities.com (using https)

1. `telnet napi.kotaksecurities.com 443`: fails sometimes, works sometimes on my local machine. Works always from Google Colab.
2. `Trying to load through Chrome browser`: sometimes fails with error: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.
3. `When using REST APIs provided by the website`: sometimes fails in TLS handshake steps from my local machine but works everytime from Google Colab. The error when using curl: `curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to napi.kotaksecurities.com:443`.

Running sslscan shows that the website uses TLS1.3.
I have also tried using a different wifi hotspot (my mobile data), but the issue persists.

What steps can I take to diagnose and then resolve the issue? I have Wireshark but I am not sure how to use it. Also, moving to a cloud server is unfortunately not an option for me.

**UPDATE: telnet on colab is using IPv4. When I run telnet -4 then the command works as intended on my network too. Seems like the server side IPv6 configuration is the culprit.**

Comment: Good diagnosis -- perhaps make that an *answer*, since it would be helpful to others with that issue.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, the issue was that the server didn't have proper IPv6 configuration. Switching to IPv4 completely solved the issue.

Diagnosis:

1. Colab was using IPv4 address by default.
2. Using IPv4 (telnet -4 napi.kotaksecurities.com 443) on my local machine never fails.
3. curl --ipv4 also started working consistently on my local machine.